# Updating lodash to the latest version to resolve a handful of vulnerabilities

Tags: linux, oracle, npm, sysadmin

I'm attempting to update lodash and have run several commands;

```
npm update -g lodash

npm update lodash --force
```

I've ran npm cache clean --force but nothing. Many of the lodash modules are outdated but I'm not able to properly update them;

`[root@*] npm list lodash* --depth1`

`npm@6.14.11 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm`

`├─┬ libnpm@3.0.1`

`│ └─┬ libnpmpublish@1.1.2`

`├── lodash._baseindexof@3.1.0`

`├─┬ lodash._baseuniq@4.6.0`

`│ ├── lodash._createset@4.0.3`

`│ └── lodash._root@3.0.1`

`├── lodash._bindcallback@3.0.1`

`├── lodash._cacheindexof@3.0.2`

`├─┬ lodash._createcache@3.1.2`

`│ └── lodash._getnative@3.9.1 deduped`

`├── lodash._getnative@3.9.1`

`├── lodash.clonedeep@4.5.0`

`├── lodash.restparam@3.6.1`

`├── lodash.union@4.6.0`

`├── lodash.uniq@4.5.0`

`├── lodash.without@4.4.0`